# IBM i SQL query, Green screen vs GUI "Run SQL Scripts"

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Question on IBM i SQL query, Green screen vs GUI "Run SQL Scripts"

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
```

..

```
SELECT * from SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
```

..

```
SELECT * FROM 
QSYS2.SYSTABLES JOIN SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS 
  ON(SYSTABLES.TABLE_NAME  = SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
  and SYSTABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA  = SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEM )

Message: [SQL0206] Column or global variable TABLE_NAME not found. Cause .
```

The above statements work IBM i Green Screen, but third one fails in ACS "Run SQL Scripts" tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of a table [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) / correlation-name to the table-reference fixes the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES AS SYSTABLES 
JOIN SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS AS SQLCOLUMNS
  ON SYSTABLES.TABLE_NAME = SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
  AND SYSTABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEM
```

See the [table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafztabref.htm) documentation for more information.

Including the library qualification also works without an explicit alias:

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
JOIN SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS
ON QSYS2.SYSTABLES.TABLE_NAME = SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
AND QSYS2.SYSTABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEM
```

Comment: OK. That works. But I am not sure why is is required. SYSTABLES.TABLE_NAME  and SQLCOLUMNS.TABLE_NAME are both valid table.field names.  Is it a System Name vs SQL naming issue? Why is GUI work different from green screen SQL?

Comment: Looks like this is indeed a `*SYS` vs. `*SQL` naming issue. If I change my green screen session to `*SQL` naming, then it issues the same error. And if I change my GUI SQL client to `system` naming, it does not exhibit the error.

Comment: Been playing with *SYS and *SQL naming and System tables for a few months, It is first time I've see this. I'd like to understand the cause.

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge The explicit library qualification is changing the implicit table-reference in *SQL mode.  I updated my answer with an example.